# Wix toolset - Major Upgrade - Would like to keep some of the files intact without removing them upon a major upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3, major-upgrade

I guess I haven't explained my requirement clearly so deleted the original question and asking again. Apologies for that !!

Basically, I have a folder containing close to 3000 files (majority of them are dlls taken from the projects that we constantly make changes to). Of these 3000 files, some needs to be untouched upon upgrades (I will use your "permanent" flag which I just tested and worked. thanks for that).

For the remaining dll files. I need a way where I can push the newly built ones as an msi package so that they are updated in the master folder on the fields without uninstalling. I couldn't take patch route as my company wants to see only one entry in the control panel > programs with latest version of the product (just like any other usual software like notepadd++ or ccleaner etc) but still updates the newly enhanced dlls.

Sometimes, we send only 1 dll to the field and most of the times we have to send them in hundreds. So a major upgrade which not only updates (even replacing is fine) the existing dlls is what am looking for. The option "afterInstallExecute" is not working for me as it is deleting the dll although I am changing the version and sending.

`<MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallExecute" AllowDowngrades="no" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of $(var.ProductName) is already installed. Setup will now exit." />`

Comment: How did you change the assembly version? MSI recognizes only first 3 digits. You can also make your components [`permanent`](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/component.html) to prevent their deletion

Comment: Dear Pavel. I have a .net project whose dll is what i need to send in the msi. I have changed the version in "assemblyinfo.cs" before building the project which changed the version of the dll. 

If I make components permanent, Can I perform Major upgrade on them to update them to newer versions?

Comment: _I need to keep some files undisturbed (database and log files)_ you can make permanent only these components. If you change only 4th digit in assembly version, msi will threat it like the same version

Comment: Pavel .. I have updated my original question. This time I tried to explain the requirement as clearly as possible. Could you kindly take a look?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're wanting a minor upgrade instead. You don't have to release this as a patch. You can also release it as an MSI. It should just have one entry in the ARP after upgrade, it will just have the version updated.

Comment: David .. Could you tell me how a minor upgrade is done as an MSI? Any link I can follow to read about this or an example? Appreciate your response